# SQL Server : select * from table where date minus one year

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

How to select year-1?

This is my code:

```
select 
    a.* 
from 
    (select 
         met_men, kli_kod, pre_kod, galutinis, savik_group, marza, 
         KLR_KOD, KLI_POZ1, KLI_POZ2, KLI_POZ3, KLG_KOD, PRE_RUS, 
         PRE_POZ1, PRE_POZ2, PRE_POZ3, PRE_POZ4, PRE_POZ5, PRE_POZ6, 
         did_dat, savi_suproc, marza_suproc, pre_ska dbo.SVF_View_10) AS a 
left outer join 
    (select 
         pre_kod, kli_kod, met_men, did_dat 
     from 
         dbo.SVF_View_10_sum 
     where 
         dateadd(year, -1, 'did_dat')) as b on a.kli_kod = b.kli_kod 
                                            and a.pre_kod = b.pre_kod 
                                            and a.did_dat = b.did_dat
```

This error occurs on the line `where DATEADD(year, -1, 'did_dat')) as b`:

> Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.

Please help me

the required data: order date, id, quantity, orderdate-1 year, quantity. It is necessary to compare the quantity sold for this year and for the last year

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you are trying to do would really help.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Comment: This is a new participant to the site.  Before downvoting, think about how you can help him/her participate better.

Comment: I agree fully. I think SO should prevent this downvote for new comer's questions until they reach certain count of questions

Answer (score 2):

You give column name in single quote dateadd(year, -1, 'did_dat') which is no need here change into dateadd(year, -1, did_dat) and when you use where clause need to give comparison operation in where clause.

so changed into

```
where did_dat <= dateadd(year, -1, did_dat)
```

but it doesn't make any sense because query should be execute on previous year against current date like

```
where did_dat <= dateadd(year, -1, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you want is:

```
select . . .
from dbo.SVF_View_10 v left outer join
     dbo.SVF_View_10_sum vs
     on v.kli_kod = vs.kli_kod and a.pre_kod = b.pre_kod and
        v.did_dat = dateadd(year, -1, vs.did_dat);
```

Notes:

- Subqueries are not necessary for this query.  I think they just make the query harder to write and to read.
- Use table aliases that are abbreviations for the table names.
- You have a date calculation in the `where` clause rather than a boolean expression.  That is causing your error.
- The date expression has a *string* for the third argument.  The would be your next error.  Strings do not refer to column names.
- I am speculating that you want the tables joined on that date expression.

Comment: Actually this is the correct answer. Both of subqueries are redundant. Just missing `a.pre_kod = b.pre_kod `. Of course, the OP perhaps is needing something like `dat_date between <yr-1 start >and <yr-1 end>` but that's hard to reveal from his question what he really wants.

Comment: the required data: order date, id, quantity, orderdate-1 year, quantity. It is necessary to compare the quantity sold for this year and for the last year

Answer (score 0):

Try This :-

```
SELECT a.*
    FROM
    (
        SELECT met_men,kli_kod,pre_kod,galutinis,savik_group,marza,KLR_KOD,LI_POZ1,
               KLI_POZ2,KLI_POZ3,KLG_KOD,PRE_RUS,PRE_POZ1,PRE_POZ2,PRE_POZ3,PRE_POZ4,
               PRE_POZ5,PRE_POZ6,did_dat,savi_suproc,marza_suproc,pre_ska
        FROM SVF_View_10_sum
    ) AS a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
            SELECT pre_kod,kli_kod,met_men,did_dat
            FROM dbo.SVF_View_10_sum
            WHERE did_dat = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, did_dat)
        ) AS b
            ON a.kli_kod = b.kli_kod AND a.pre_kod = b.pre_kod AND a.did_dat = b.did_dat;
```

Comment: quotes around `did_dat` needed to be removed.

Comment: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: `WHERE did_dat = DATEADD(YEAR, -1, did_dat)` - and when is this gonna happen? ))

Comment: Did-dat is datetime column. When query run did-dat is not converting

Comment: Please Check Now